# VTK arbitrary-order Lagrange elements - node positions/ordering on reference tri/quad/hex/tet elements

Tags: finite-element, vtk

VTK has had support for visualizing [arbitrary-order Lagrange elements](https://www.kitware.com/modeling-arbitrary-order-lagrange-finite-elements-in-the-visualization-toolkit/#:%7E:text=The%20new%20cells%20in%20VTK,may%20vary%20in%20Lagrange%20cells.) for a while now, but there aren't many resources out there (as far as I know) facilitating their use. Notably, these elements rely on a particular "onion-like" node ordering which many solvers (including mine) don't use by default. This means that people developing high-order solvers have to generate specific sets of visualization nodes which conform to such an ordering in order to use these VTK element types.

What I would really like is some way of generating unisolvent sets of nodes on reference (e.g. right-angled) triangles, tetrahedra, quadrilaterals, and hexahedra for a given polynomial degree, with the ordering given according to VTK's convention. Does such a tool exist? Even a database of hard-coded coordinates for different polynomial degrees (say, up to 10) would save me, and probably many others, a lot of time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the specific ordering bother you? It's just a permutation of any other ordering you might choose, and easy to put into a permutation table.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I agree, reordering isn't conceptually difficult at all, but it requires generating and tabulating a permutation for every polynomial degree and element type, and I was trying to avoid having to do that if there was a faster way. As the nodes that I use for plotting can be arbitrary, I was interested in choosing them to be compatible with VTK's format without the need for reordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a tool exists, and I came across it a few weeks ago. In fact, it is mentioned in a [comment](https://www.kitware.com/modeling-arbitrary-order-lagrange-finite-elements-in-the-visualization-toolkit/#comment-1415) of the linked post. Here is the repository: https://github.com/ju-kreber/paraview-scripts

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.